# How to use groupby method to get table specific datas of particular id in sequelize postgres

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have three tables;
1. ticket
2. login
3. ticketmember

I have tickedId and memberId(this is coming from login table) in my ticketmember table, i done this using sequelize include method(
  for memberId using "as" in login table)

In my app, member can have multiple tickets.My ticketmember table data looks like this

[image]

I want to take all tickets of members,
  for eg: member 1 have three ticketId i want to find that data of specific member.

I am writing api to get ticketmember table:

My api.js:

```
exports.getTicketMemberAll = (req, res) => {
    TicketMember.findAll({
        include: [{
          model: Ticket
        }, {
          model: Login,
          as: 'member',
        }],
      })
      .then(data => {
        res.status(200).send(data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send(err.message)
      });
  };
```

My response:

```
[
    {
      id: 1,
      isActive: true,
      ticketId: 1,
      ticket: {
        status: "New",
      }
      memberId: 3,
      member: {
        username: "zen",
      }
    }
    {
      id: 1,
      isActive: true,
      ticketId: 2,
      ticket: {
        status: "New",
      }
      memberId: 3,
      member: {
        username: "zen",
      }
    }
  ]
```

My desired outcome:

I have memberId: 3 in two objects, So i want to combine the objects with the related tickets.

Answer (score 0):

It's a case of many to many associations so you can use this feature of Sequelize

```
Ticket.belongsToMany(Member, {through: 'TicketMember'});
Member.belongsToMany(Ticket, {through: 'TicketMember'});
```

Then you will get access to getter and setter methods like this

```
ticket.getMembers and member.getTickets
```

to query you can use

```
Member.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Ticket,
  }]
});
```

Please reference Belongs-To-Many associations section [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html)

It should work let me know if any errors

Comment: it throwing error: error: column "TicketMember.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Comment: can you share the response format you need in your question

Comment: I dont know to how the grouped response will come. so i dont have expected format.

Comment: just share rough requirement i will write query

Comment: do you need ticket info of all memmber like this 

member1 => ticket1, ticket2,
member2 => ticket2, ticket3

am i right?